# Problems to insert a new item in Mongo database using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

Can someone explain to me why whenever I'm using localhost:27017 to connects with my database I get the MongooseErros: buffering timed out after 10000ms, but it doesn't happen if I put 127.0.0.1:27017? OBS: I don't have atlas instaled.

This is the code that gives me the error:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser: true,});
    
const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });
    
const kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });

kitty.save().then(() => console.log('meow'));
```

If I change the localhost to 127.0.0.1 it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must refer you to mongoose official website [Mongoose Connections](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connections) which does not explanes exact reason for that but mostly I learned it depends on which operating system you use.

ofcurse I suggest you to make a file connect.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connectDB = async (url) => {
  return mongoose.connect(url);
};

export default connectDB;
```

then in your server.js file

```
import app from './app/Application';

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB");
    app.listen(300, () => console.log('Server is listening in port 3000 ...'));
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

it will works currectly and does't start your server until your database connection is ready.